# The problem with the gradient to create a pseudo button

Tags: html, css, button, gradient

I need to make a button that would look the same in any modern browser and on any OS (`appearance: button` - this is not a solution for me!).
[These are the 4 stages (without disabled stage) of the button I want to recreate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roUJo.png)

I made a wrapper, but there is a [problem with the gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjdsP.png). This can be solved by copying the image of the original button and inserting it as a background, but I think this is a bad decision. My opinion is that the gradient is a better solution for zooming than the temporary version with: `background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/lmEjKKe.png')`.

```js
//
function setBtnHover(element, value) {
 //
 element.dataset.hover = value;
}

//
var lastBtnMouseDown = null;

//
function setBtnMouseDown(element, value, e) {
 //
 if (element !== null) {
  //
  element.dataset.mouseDown = value;
  //
  if (value) {
   //
   if (lastBtnMouseDown !== null)
    //
    lastBtnMouseDown.dataset.click = false;

   //
   element.dataset.click = true;
   //
   lastBtnMouseDown = element;
  }

  //
  e.stopPropagation();
 //
 } else if (!value) {
  //
  if (lastBtnMouseDown !== null) {
   //
   lastBtnMouseDown.dataset.mouseDown = value;
  }
 } else {
  //
  lastBtnMouseDown.dataset.click = false;
  //
  lastBtnMouseDown = null;
 }
}
```

```css
.button {
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  height: 22px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #003c74;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  font: 13.3333px MS Shell Dlg \32;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/3Jwqiw1.png');
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.button[data-hover=false][data-click=true] {
 background: radial-gradient(white 60%, blue 100%);
}

.button[data-hover=true][data-mouse-down=true] {
 padding-left: 1px;
 background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/lmEjKKe.png');
}

.button[data-hover=true][data-mouse-down=false] {
 background: radial-gradient(white 60%, orange 100%);
}
```

```html
<body onmousedown="setBtnMouseDown(null, true)" onmouseup="setBtnMouseDown(null, false)">

<p style="padding-left: 1px;"><span class="button" data-hover="false" data-mouse-down="false" data-click="false" onmouseover="setBtnHover(this, true)" onmouseout="setBtnHover(this, false)" onmousedown="setBtnMouseDown(this, true, event)" onmouseup="setBtnMouseDown(this, false, event)">BUTTON</span></p>

<p><button>BUTTON</button></p>

</body>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wd4m6qg/5/

Comment: "but there is a problem with the gradient" - what is the actual problem? You never explain.

Comment: tried to use the code from 'http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/' ? it should provide what you need

Comment: @SergChernata I can't find the values to simulate the correct stroke. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjdsP.png

Comment: @MarouenMhiri I opened it, but: _"Page not found The page you requested wasn't found on this server. Please check your request for typing errors and retry. You can also use the links on this site to reach the wanted page."_

Comment: colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @MarouenMhiri, Yes, I noticed that there is an error in the link. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pseudo-classes or pseudo-elements, you can use classes to apply the CSS (I think it is simpler and cleaner code), and instead of a radial gradient background you can use a box-shadow in "inset" mode to create a thick inner border (plus a solid background color, or linear-gradient):

```
.my-button.over {
    /* background: radial-gradient(white 60%, orange 100%); */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em orange inset;
}
```

You can also simplify the logic by adding event listeners to selectors that you want to target, like this:

```
var mybutton = document.querySelector('.my-button'); // single element
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.my-button'); // many elements
```

Then create some functions that add/remove classes to/from the targeted element:

```
function overButton() {
    this.classList.add('over')
}
```

Attach the functions to the elements using the correct event listener.  (You could also add conditional logic to check whether or not a class is already added to a particular button.)

```
mybutton.addEventListener('mouseout', outButton); // single element
// see my JS Bin for attaching to multiple elements.
```

Here's my JS Bin:

http://jsbin.com/sehucak/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Excellent! Brilliant solution. I'm sorry, but I can't support your answer. But, if I get 15 reputation points, I promise I'll add you another +1.

Comment: And yes, the solution looks like this: `.button[data-hover=false][data-click=true] {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #8bade4 inset;
}` ... `.button[data-hover=true][data-mouse-down=false] {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px orange inset;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the screenshot, I'm guessing this is the effect that you're looking for. I am stacking pseudo elements to create the desired effect.

```js
//
function setBtnHover(element, value) {
  //
  element.dataset.hover = value;
}

//
var lastBtnMouseDown = null;

//
function setBtnMouseDown(element, value, e) {
  //
  if (element !== null) {
    //
    element.dataset.mouseDown = value;
    //
    if (value) {
      //
      if (lastBtnMouseDown !== null)
        //
        lastBtnMouseDown.dataset.click = false;

      //
      element.dataset.click = true;
      //
      lastBtnMouseDown = element;
    }

    //
    e.stopPropagation();
    //
  } else if (!value) {
    //
    if (lastBtnMouseDown !== null) {
      //
      lastBtnMouseDown.dataset.mouseDown = value;
    }
  } else {
    //
    lastBtnMouseDown.dataset.click = false;
    //
    lastBtnMouseDown = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  width: 70px;
  height: 23px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #003c74;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  font: 13.3333px MS Shell Dlg \32;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.button::before {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/3Jwqiw1.png');
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

.button::after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  content: "";
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button[data-hover=false][data-click=true]::before {
  background: radial-gradient(white 60%, blue 100%);
}

.button[data-hover=true][data-mouse-down=true]::before {
  padding-left: 1px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/lmEjKKe.png');
}

.button[data-hover=true][data-mouse-down=false]::before {
  background: radial-gradient(white 60%, orange 100%);
}
```

```html
<body onmousedown="setBtnMouseDown(null, true)" onmouseup="setBtnMouseDown(null, false)">

  <p style="padding-left: 1px;"><span class="button" data-hover="false" data-mouse-down="false" data-click="false" onmouseover="setBtnHover(this, true)" onmouseout="setBtnHover(this, false)" onmousedown="setBtnMouseDown(this, true, event)" onmouseup="setBtnMouseDown(this, false, event)">BUTTON</span></p>

  <p><button>BUTTON</button></p>

</body>
```

Comment: Perhaps it requires the union of four `linear-gradient` (top, right, bottom, left)?

Comment: @Injector I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: `background: linear-gradient(to left, #ffffff 98%, #ff5d00 2%);background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 95%,#ff5d00 100%);`

Comment: But this does not give two gradients.

Comment: `background: linear-gradient(to left, #ffffff 98%, #ff5d00 2%), linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 95%,#ff5d00 100%);` Also does not work